# Recyclerview doesn't working for my code to display records from several keys created by several users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve cases data created by several users and display them in a recyclerview. However, it stop and go to previous app screen. Is there easy way to retrieve firebasedata created by several users in a recyclerview.

Here my code:

```
private void setRecyclerView() {

    DatabaseReference caseRef;

    myrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myLawyerRecycler);
    myrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mLawyerData = new ArrayList<>();

    final List<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    caseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cases");

    caseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String userkey = ds.getKey();
                mStrings.add(userkey);
            }
            String[] strings = new String[mStrings.size()];
            strings = mStrings.toArray(strings);
            count = strings.length;


            Log.d("testrecycler", "Number of Records: " + strings.length);
            Log.d("testrecycler", "Number of Records: " + strings[0]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    DatabaseReference caseRef1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

         //update recyclerview list
        caseRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cases").child((strings[i]));
        caseRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    LawyerData data = ds.getValue(LawyerData.class);
                    mLawyerData.add(data);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
    mAttorneyListAdapter = new AttorneyListAdapter(mLawyerData);
    myrecyclerView.setAdapter(mAttorneyListAdapter);
}
```

Here is data structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkP2d.png)

Comment: It seems the problem on the for loop and the call below which does not except  strings[i]. if i changed to 0 for example it will show the recyclerview.    
   
caseRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cases").child((strings[i]));
        caseRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to get it with below code

```
    DatabaseReference caseRef;

    myrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myLawyerRecycler);
    myrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mLawyerData = new ArrayList<>();

    caseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cases");

    caseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot casesDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (casesDataSnapshot != null) {
                    for (DataSnapshot subDataSnapshot : casesDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        LawyerData data = subDataSnapshot.getValue(LawyerData.class);
                        mLawyerData.add(data);
                    }

                }
            }
            mAttorneyListAdapter = new AttorneyListAdapter(mLawyerData);
            myrecyclerView.setAdapter(mAttorneyListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```